# Typescript error when building nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I m actually trying to developp an application with nodejs and typescript and I m facing a problem at tsc compilation.

I got this error when running my code (it seems that the external module cannot be load) :

```
[09:20:29] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.5.0
[09:20:30] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.5.0
[09:20:30] [tsc] > F:/SkeletonProject/typings/node/node.d.ts(198,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DataView'.
[09:20:30] [tsc] > F:/SkeletonProject/typings/node/node.d.ts(212,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[09:20:30] [tsc] > F:/SkeletonProject/typings/node/node.d.ts(221,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[09:20:30] [tsc] > F:/SkeletonProject/typings/node/node.d.ts(231,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
```

Here's my gulpfile :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');

gulp.task('boot', ['compileBoot'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/src/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist/'))
});

gulp.task('compileBoot', ['compileApp'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['./boot/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./boot'))
});


gulp.task('compileApp', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/src/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist/'))
});


gulp.start('boot');
```

And here's the code that doesn't want to compile and throw me the exception :

```
/// <reference path="../typings/glob/glob.d.ts" />
import glob = require('glob');
console.log("zfazf");
```

What is wrong in this piece of code ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is wrong in this piece of code

Nothing. You need to get the definition files `node.d.ts` from the beta branch manually till it is released : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/4249

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually looking into the issues to fix my problem

Comment: It seems that I already use the latest version of the node.d.ts (from 1.5 alpha) and it doesn't change anything :-/